# scene transition return to wrong recyclerview item

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-transitions

I have a recyclerview filled with items. I use the firestore as datastore. Here is how I set the transition name during onBindViewHolder in my adapter.

```
expressionView.setTransitionName(MainActivity.FIELD_EXPRESSION + snapshot.getId());
        definitionView.setTransitionName(MainActivity.FIELD_DEFINITION + snapshot.getId());
        buttonsView.setTransitionName("buttons" + snapshot.getId());
```

And this is how I call the detail activity in my fragment:

```
ActivityOptions options = ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(getActivity(),
            Pair.create(expressionView, ViewCompat.getTransitionName(expressionView)),
            Pair.create(definitionView, ViewCompat.getTransitionName(definitionView)),
            Pair.create(buttonsView, ViewCompat.getTransitionName(buttonsView)));

    Log.d(TAG, "transitionName: "+ ViewCompat.getTransitionName(expressionView));
    Log.d(TAG, "transitionName: "+ ViewCompat.getTransitionName(definitionView));
    Log.d(TAG, "transitionName: "+ ViewCompat.getTransitionName(buttonsView));

    /*ActivityOptions options = ActivityOptions.makeCustomAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim
            .activity_in, R.anim.activity_out);*/

    startActivity(intent, options.toBundle());
```

And in the detail activity I set the transition name as follows:

```
mExpressionView.setTransitionName(MainActivity.FIELD_EXPRESSION + mEntryId);
    mDefinitionView.setTransitionName(MainActivity.FIELD_DEFINITION + mEntryId);
    mButtonsView.setTransitionName("buttons" + mEntryId);
```

The transition from recyclerview item to detail activity works fine. But when I click the back button, the transition doesn't go back to the clicked item. In fact more than one item are animated.
I have also enabled shared element transition in my style

Answer (score 0):

Calling `mAdapter.setHasStableIds(true);` solve the problem